# How do you redirect a custom generated URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write an extension for personal use. *Background.js* file where I want to take a url - detect an integer from within it - redirect it to a new URL with the string concatenated in between. But it doesn't seem to work (I'm new). This is a very specific case for personal use. Here is my example code so far (of course the URLs are sample):

```
const abc = "https://www.google.com/anc/wddsd/";
const xyz = "/tracking/file/subsystem";
var res = url.split('/')[4];  //can I even access the URL before the function begins?
```

Say there is a Numeric Digit that occurs just after `/wddsd/` and I want to extract it from the original URL and place it in the redirected URL.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {

      return {
        redirectUrl: 
        abc + res + xyz
    };
    },

    {
      urls: [
        "*//www.google.com/*"
      ],
      types: [
        "main_frame",
        "sub_frame",
        "stylesheet",
        "script",
        "image",
        "object",
        "xmlhttprequest",
        "other"
      ]
    },
    ["blocking"]
  );
```

update: The permissions of my `manifest.json` are:

```
"permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://google.com/*"]
```

Comment: What is happening when you run this code?

Comment: @SujeetSinha I am not being redirected. Nothing happens, I get taken to the web address I type on the URL bar.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: `var num = parseInt("https://www.google.com/anc/wddsd".match(/\d+/),10)
console.log(num);` Not sure I am right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey to anyone stumbling upon this in the future, I fixed it myself by essentially replacing

```
var res = url.split('/')[4];
```

with

```
var res = details.url.split('/')[4];
```

and putting it inside the function. Hooray.